# single html page on disk request for localhost CORS error

Tags: javascript

everyone:
I am a beginner on fort-end, create a single html file on disk.For example,"D:/index.html".
Then I start a node.js server。

Run the node.js server, and open the browser on page of "index.html", CORS error occur.
I know add js code " res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );"  on node.js server, it can avoid CORS error.
My question is "single html page located on disk, I think it also come from localhost, why request to localhost server can trigger CORS???"

Comment: Please post your server code. And also the part of your frontend code that trigger the error. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when we say the same origin the port, protocol, and the host should be the same for both.
please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).